# Should I use ArithmeticException or IllegalArgumentException and what's the differance?

Tags: java, exception

If I've a method such as `getFactorial(int n)` that should fail for negative inputs, should it `throw` an `ArithmeticException` or an `IllegalArgumentException`? Negative numbers are definitely illegal arguments; also they are a kinda nonsense arithmetically. Does it matter which or are they just an indication to the programmer as to why the method can't process the input?

Comment: `IllegalArgumentException`, because the failure is occurring because of an argument outside the acceptable range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArithmeticException` is for

> Thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition has occurred.

`IllegalArgumentException` is for

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or
>   inappropriate argument.

In your case it is a bad argument provided to the method, so `IllegalArgumentException` seems finer.

I think that the `ArithmeticException` risen in a method makes more sense for computations that would create arithmetic errors and where you cannot guess the problem just by checking the argument(s) in entry of the method.

Comment: I guess that makes more sense as you could "guess the problem just by checking ..." even though negative factorials don't exist so ARE an arithmetic error

Comment: . So, is it just a judgment call as to what should appear in the stack trace ie. IllegalArgumentException - Negative factorial or ArithmeticException  - Negative factorial ?

Comment: You are totally right. It is semantics matter. But why do we define specific exceptions and we don't use the generic Exception or RuntimeException ? Because semantics matters. For example when you get an IllegalArgumentException, you know that the problem comes from an invalid  input. If it is suitable, you can even catch the exception and ask for the client  another input. When you get an ArithmeticException, you know that is an arithmetic problem but you don't know if the problem is related to an invalid input. The error origin that is specific becomes shadowed by the ArithmeticException.

Answer (score 0):

An `IllegalArgumentException` should be used in this case, as you don't want the user passing a negative argument (parameter) to the method.

An `ArithmeticException` should be used if a computed value doesn't make sense.

For example, the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) for `ArithmeticException` states:

> Thrown when an exceptional arithmetic condition has occurred. For example, an integer "divide by zero" throws an instance of this class.